# Updating Customer with REST API results in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: rest, api, acumatica, guzzle

I'm updating AR Customer records via the Contract-Based REST API using `PHP` & `Guzzle 6` and am getting a `500 Internal Server Error` response back.

The error message in the response is:

```
{
   "message": "An error has occurred.",
   "exceptionMessage": "Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Api.ContractBased.Models.EntityValueField' to type 'PX.Api.ContractBased.Models.EntitySearchField'.",
   "exceptionType": "System.InvalidCastException",
   "stackTrace": "... see below ..."
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
at PX.Api.ContractBased.OData.FilterVisitor.SetNullableCondition(BinaryOperatorNode nodeIn, String nullCondition, String regularCondition)
at PX.Api.ContractBased.OData.FilterVisitor.VisitRoot(SingleValueNode root)
at PX.Api.ContractBased.OData.Helpers.FillRestQueryOptions(IEdmModel edmModel, EntityImpl entity, String filter, String select, String expand, String custom)
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

> My sincerest appologies for adding the **entire** stack trace, but I thought it might be helpful.

At first, I thought that it might have something to do with the URL of the request, but after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123906/11321261) answer from a similar question it does not appear to be related to the parameters passed in the URL?

I have already found a 'solution/workaround' by removing the `CustomerID` from the request body, but it seems a bit odd that this is needed in order to get the request to work?

I had a look at the [documentation for updating a record](https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=af48c02a-afbc-4fdb-b1e5-635ac7ebbaf1), but don't see anything related to 'remove the `key` field when using the `filter` parameter in the request URL'.

#### This request returns the 500 Internal Server Error:

PUT `entity/Default/18.200.001/Customer?$filter=CustomerID%20eq%20%27100000044%27&$select=CustomerID`

```
{
   "CustomerClass": {
      "value": "CUSTOMER_CLASS"
   },
   "CustomerID": {
      "value": "100000044"
   },
   "CustomerName": {
      "value": "Christiaan Raubenheimer"
   },
   "MainContact": {
      "Address": {
         "AddressLine1": {
            "value": "Street Line 1"
         },
         "AddressLine2": {
            "value": "Stree Line 2"
         },
         "City": {
            "value": "City"
         },
         "Country": {
            "value": "ZA"
         },
         "PostalCode": {
            "value": "0000"
         },
         "State": {
            "value": "State"
         }
      },
      "Attention": {
         "value": "Christiaan Raubenheimer"
      },
      "DisplayName": {
         "value": "Company Name"
      },
      "Email": {
         "value": "...email address..."
      },
      "JobTitle": {
         "value": "Company Name"
      },
      "Phone1": {
         "value": "0000000000"
      }
   }
}
```

#### This request returns a 200 Success Response:

PUT `entity/Default/18.200.001/Customer?$filter=CustomerID%20eq%20%27100000044%27&$select=CustomerID`

```
{
   "CustomerClass": {
      "value": "CUSTOMER_CLASS"
   },
   "CustomerName": {
      "value": "Christiaan Raubenheimer"
   },
   "MainContact": {
      "Address": {
         "AddressLine1": {
            "value": "Street Line 1"
         },
         "AddressLine2": {
            "value": "Stree Line 2"
         },
         "City": {
            "value": "City"
         },
         "Country": {
            "value": "ZA"
         },
         "PostalCode": {
            "value": "0000"
         },
         "State": {
            "value": "State"
         }
      },
      "Attention": {
         "value": "Christiaan Raubenheimer"
      },
      "DisplayName": {
         "value": "Company Name"
      },
      "Email": {
         "value": "...email address..."
      },
      "JobTitle": {
         "value": "Company Name"
      },
      "Phone1": {
         "value": "0000000000"
      }
   }
}
```

In summary, it looks like it's required to remove the `CustomerID` from the request body as demonstrated above, but could it be that I am perhaps missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve information or to update a record? Normally the PUT request is used in order to update or create new records while the filter parameter is more used in order to select a list or a specific record.

Comment: Hi there @samol518 I am trying to update a record. Looking at the user documentation linked, the `$filter` parameter can be used to:

To specify filtering conditions that identify the record to be updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably due to the fact that you are mixing multiple ways of selecting a record in order to update it.

You are using the 2 following ways:

- The Filter parameter in the URL
- The Key field in the body of the record

Please consider only using one of these method.

Comment: Thanks @samol518, this was my suspicion too!